# Is EXT JS a good alternative to JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, extjs

a colleague suggested I give this framework a try. My question is, does anyone have any feedback about this, is it better than using JQuery

UPDATE: I found this posting which partially answers some of my questions

[How different is Ext JS from others like jQuery and Mootools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835755/how-different-is-ext-js-from-others-like-jquery-and-mootools)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two parts to the Ext framework. [Ext Core](http://www.extjs.com/products/extcore/) was invented as a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) competitor but honestly if you're trying to do what jQuery does, just use jQuery. It's more popular, it'll be easier to find answers, etc.

[ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) is a full-blown RIA framework with a rich library of widgets. You might say that it competes with jQuery UI but [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is a much less rich set of components so they're not really competitors as such.

Also, ExtJS is released under either the [GPL or a commercial license](http://www.extjs.com/products/license.php). You may find that to be a problem.

For rich Javascript frameworks, I tend to favour [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or possibly [SmartClient](http://www.smartclient.com/).

Comment: @Cletus - thanks, I think my question was too specific , you have thrown two more possibilities into the mix :) .

Comment: @cletus the core is under mit license if I am not wrong. the full Ext JS is under GPL (and the change of license make quiet a controversy)

Comment: What about using YUI and JQuery together. Does that sound like a good solution?

Comment: You can do that. YUI has its own inbuilt functions for server callbacks however so I'd recommend keeping it within one framework where possible but you can mix them.

Comment: I am not a fan of jquery style, I much prefer Ext's OO style. Since I already use Ext at work for our RIA, I use Ext core for websites that use progressive enhancement... Having said that, it's true that you could have an easier time finding answers for jquery. I, however, have no trouble when posting questions at ext-js's forum

Answer (score 2):

I say that ExtJS is much more comparable to [DHTMLX](http://www.dhtmlx.com/) than jQuery when it comes to the richness of features.  It's also released under GPL or commercial license.  You might want to check it out as well.

Answer (score 1):

it depend what you want to do, but ext-core is basically the same things as jquery. The full blow Ext JS is more a full framework for building RIA (lot of components: grids , tree, formpanel).

If you are looking only adding ajax bits and pieces for your website extcore could make it.

Comment: @RageZ - so it's the best option for RIA and for AJAX?

Comment: I have been using it for 1 year and I would say for building a real desktop look and feel application that the best one around. 

The Ext core was introduced later with the 3.0 release, the goal of the project was to provide a replacement for Dojo and Jquery and prototype so you can do about the same level of effect/CSS3 query/ajax as other popular framework.

If you are looking making RIA stuff I advice you ExtJS. If it's only website ajaxification jquery have a better support like Cletus pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on jquery, but my project expected me to work on Ext JS 4. Initially i thought its just another JavaScript framework. But it was huge shock as i found it quite difficult to learn initially.

But slowly I have started getting hold of Ext JS and started appreciating its design philosophy of OOPs. So its quite different than other JavaScript frameworks. You can achieve equally good RIA in either of these frameworks though. Also Ext JS 4 is quite improved from previous versions. You can try Sencha Architect IDE of Ext JS; though its not free. Secha achitect allows you to drag and drop UI components.